# Karate get's hang while passing tag from the command line

Tags: karate

DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - waiting for 5 features to complete

My CLI:
clean test -Dtest=TestRunner#testParallel -DPATH="/api"  -DTAGS="@tag1"

Karate Version
com.intuit.karate
karate-apache
0.9.6

Comment: that's a very old version of karate that is not supported any more. upgrade. and if you still see problems, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue